# Existence of a rational function on a nonsingular curve with a simple zero at P and order 0 at Q

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes

Let $X$ be a nonsingular curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ (by curve over $k$, I mean an integral separated scheme of finite type over $k$ which has dimension 1). Let $P$ and $Q$ be distinct closed points of $X$.

**Question:** Does there exist a rational function $f$ on $X$ satisfying both of the following two properties:

1. $f$ has a simple zero at $P$;
2. $f_Q\in \mathcal{O}_Q^*$, i.e. $f$ does not have a pole or a zero at $Q$.

Equivalently, does there exist a rational function $f$ on $X$ such that the principal (Weil) divisor $\operatorname{div}(f)$ given by $f$ is of the form
$$ \operatorname{div}(f) = P + D, $$
where $D\in \operatorname{Div}(X)$, and $P,Q\notin \operatorname{Supp}(D)$.

Equivalently-equivalently, is $P$ linearly equivalent to a divisor $D$ with $P,Q\notin\operatorname{Supp}(D)$?

**Motivation:** I'd like to be able to say that, given closed points $P_1,\ldots,P_n\in X$, any divisor $D$ on $X$ is linearly equivalent to one without $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ in its support.

**EDIT:** My background is Chapters I and II in Hartshorne, so I'd like to be able to prove this without, e.g., Riemann-Roch.

Comment: Sure, just choose a divisor $D$ disjoint from $P,Q$ and of degree 
large enough that Riemann-Roch says 
$$
h^0(D-P) = h^0(D-2P) + 1 = h^0(D-P-Q) + 1.
$$

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies See my edit.

Comment: I would say that Riemann-Roch is the most basic and the most powerful tool for constructing functions on curves. Further, it's proof is far more elementary (and down-to-earth) than much of the material in Chapter II of Hartshorne. So I'd suggest learning about RR and using it for problems of this sort, unless you have some good reason why a non-RR proof would be useful. (E.g., are you hoping to work on an analogous problem where RR is not available or useful? If so, it would be helpful to identify said problem.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embed $C$ in a projective space. Take a generic linear section through $P$ that doesn't contain $Q$. Divide by a generic linear section that contains neither $P$ nor $Q$. This is down to earth and needs only Bertini.

**UPD:** In response to a completely reasonable comment, here is how to choose an embedding. We may assume that $C$ is irreducible. Cover the curve by finitely many affine opens $C=\cup U_i$. Think of each $U_i$ as of a smooth curve in $\mathbb{A}^{n_i}\subset\mathbb{P}^{n_i}$ and take the closure $C_i$. Now, we have a natural morphism $U_i\to C_i$ that extends to $f_i:C\to Y_i$ (valuative criterion of properness [H, Chapter II]). Consider the diagonal map sending $C\to \Pi_i C_i$ this would give the desired embedding into a projective curve (take the closure of the image).

Comment: Well embedding in projective space is usually proved using Riemann-Roch...   
Though there might be a more elementary proof.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies You are absolutely right, I had to update my answer in order to keep my down-to-earth promise.

Comment: I could be recalling things incorrectly, but 'from scratch', it's not clear that an abstract curve has any non-zero functions on it. If the questioner will allow that his curve is projective, then probably using hyperplanes containing and not containing points one can construct an answer.  In other words, I don't think it is 'from scratch' possible to show that an abstract curve is projective.

Comment: @aginensky What's wrong with my argument showing that the curve is quasi-projective?

Comment: Nothing. I didn't see  it somehow  when I posted my comment.  You have indeed kept within the OP's definition of elementary.  I will scratch my head on how RR isn't elementary but the Valuative Criteria for Properness is elementary, but you are correct.

Comment: @aginensky We are on the same page here.